# Алгоритм шифрования AES - как шифровать с ключом который = 20 байт?

Tags: шифрование, криптография, aes

Реализовал стандартный алгоритм шифрования AES, размер блока 128 бит, ключ 128 бит, к примеру строка состоит из 31 байта:
"Two One Nine Two One Three four" = 31 байт (дополняем нулем до 32 байт)
Ключ: Thats my Kung Fu = 16 байт
В данный момент из исходного текста выбираем первые 16 байт и делаем все преобразования с данным ключом (Add Roundkey, Mixcolumns ...), затем следующие 16 байт исходного текста с тем же ключом.
Вопрос: что если ключ будет к примеру 32 байтным или 48, т.е. понятно, что все разбивается на блоки по 16 байт и выполняются преобразования, но в какой последовательности ? 
Это правильная картинка ? Если исходный текст = 16 байт и ключ = 48 байт, то ключ разбивается на 3 блока и последовательно 3 раза выполняется шифрование с каждым блоком, это правильно ? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9osvv.jpg

Answer (score 1):

AES может работать только со 128/192/256-битными (16/24/32 байтными) ключами. Если у вас ключ другой длины - придется его увеличивать/уменьшать.

Comment: я эту информацию знаю! но у меня вопрос, если ключ будет 48 байт (посмотрите пожалуйста картинку) а исходный текст - всего 16 байт, можно ли этот исходный текст зашифровать 3 раза т.е. пропустить через все методы но с разными ключами (1-й раз 1-й блок ключа 16 байт и т.д.) ???

Comment: Можно, только зачем?

Comment: В первую очередь вам не надо писать свою реализацию без очень веских на то причин. Во вторую очередь вам следует посмотреть заведомо рабочую реализацию, например в OpenSSL.

Comment: у меня уже написана моя реализация, просто ее надо дополнить немного, чтоб работало с 192 и 256 битными ключами

Comment: подскажите, а как выполнить операцию Add Roundkey когда используем 192-bit ключ, если у нас исходный текст содержит матрицу 4х4 а раундовый ключ - матрица 4х6 ? или я не так понял как сделать матрицу раундовых ключей ?

Comment: Вам уже было сказано: смотрите имеющиеся реализации. И даже было сказано где именно смотреть.